# Getting or setting the audio format that AUGraphAddRenderNotify receives

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

Is it possible to set the audio format for an `AUGraphAddRenderNotify` callback? If not, is it possible just to see what the format is at init time?

I have a very simple AUGraph which plays audio from a `kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer` to a `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO`. I'm doing some live processing on the audio so I've added a `AUGraphAddRenderNotify` callback to the graph to do it there. This all works fine, but when I initialise the graph, I need to set up a couple buffers and some other data for my processing, and I need to know what format will be supplied in the callback. (On some devices it's interleaved, on others it's not — this is fine I just need to know).

Here's the setup:

```
NewAUGraph(&audioUnitGraph);

AUNode playerNode;
AUNode outputNode;

AudioComponentDescription playerDescription = {
    .componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator,
    .componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer,
    .componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
};

AudioComponentDescription outputDescription = {
    .componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output,
    .componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO,
    .componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
};

AUGraphAddNode(audioUnitGraph, &playerDescription, &playerNode);
AUGraphAddNode(audioUnitGraph, &outputDescription, &outputNode);

AUGraphOpen(audioUnitGraph);

AUGraphNodeInfo(audioUnitGraph, playerNode, NULL, &playerAudioUnit);
AUGraphNodeInfo(audioUnitGraph, outputNode, NULL, &outputAudioUnit);

// Tried adding all manner of AudioUnitSetProperty() calls here to set the AU formats

AUGraphConnectNodeInput(audioUnitGraph, playerNode, 0, outputNode, 0);
AUGraphAddRenderNotify(audioUnitGraph, render, (__bridge void *)self);

AUGraphInitialize(audioUnitGraph);

// Some time later...
// - Set up audio file in the file player
// - Start the graph with AUGraphStart()
```

I can understand that altering the formats used by the two audio units may not have any effect on the format 'seen' at the point the `AUGraph` renders into its callback (as this is downstream of them), but surely there is a way to know at init time what that format will be?

Comment: How to use `kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer ` unit to play audio file?Could you show you show some sample code?